# installed aptana 3.0, and now php on localhost no longer works

Tags: aptana3

Windows XP with Apache Server and PHP installed and working.  Installed Aptana 3.0 and now PHP from the localhost is no longer working.  It just shows the code (or parts of it).

I have been working with php files on the localhost for weeks with no problems.  Since I installed Aptana 3.0 a few days ago, these local (and simple) php files do not render as php.

Update: The php fails to render when I drag/drop from Windows Explorer.  This worked before the install of Aptana.  If I enter the address directly into the address bar, it works correctly.

When I drag/drop, the following is in the address bar:

file:///C:/apache/htdocs/btb_sandbox/array_functions.php